# Como consigo usar o Scrapy no Anaconda

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy, anaconda

Olá, estou tendo problemas para criar um projeto com Scrapy.
Estou estudando ciência de dados na faculdade e tenho que usar o Scrapy. Estou usando pelo Anaconda. Primeiro através do Spider IDE(Anaconda Navigator), agora estou tentando pelo prompt mesmo.
O problema é para usar mesmo, pois não estou conseguindo seguir o tutorial do Scrapy:
[image: Foto do tutorial]

Segundo o tutorial eu devo usar o comando`scrapy startproject tutorial`mas ao usar tenho o seguinte erro:

```
  (base) C:\Users\wid>scrapy startproject tutorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 252, in __init__

    log_scrapy_info(self.settings)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\log.py", line 149, in log_sc
rapy_info
    for name, version in scrapy_components_versions()
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py", line 35, in sc
rapy_components_versions
    ("pyOpenSSL", _get_openssl_version()),
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py", line 43, in _g
et_openssl_version
    import OpenSSL
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>

    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\bind
ing.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: O sistema operacional não pode executar %1.

(base) C:\Users\wid>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já repeti o código com meu Environment ativado e o erro é o mesmo...

Não achei nenhuma solução para esse problema, e só estou procurando um jeito de usar o Scrapy!!
PS: A instalação do Scrapy não deu nenhum problema, só na hora de usar mesmo.

Comment: Estou usando o scrapy aqui sem problemas, mas não uso anaconda; Instalei pelo pip mesmo...

Comment: Tive vários problemas mas consegui instalar pelo pip, valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então primeiro, você deve executar o **Anaconda Prompt** como **administrador**, setar pelo o comando **cd** o diretório que você quer guardar o projeto e em seguida criar o projeto pelo comando **scrapy startproject seuprojeto** , não sei se é bem isso, lembrando também que tu precisa ter o scrapy, tu pode instalar pela a IDE de Libraries do Anaconda

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, Já consegui. Eu estava fazendo isso mas quando o Scrappy era instalado pelo Anaconda não rodava, daí tive que instalar através do pip